# Curl only load first page why is wordpress troublesome

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, curl

I'm trying to change product page, but when I do that, it loads the wrong url.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<select class="form-control" name="pagecall" id="pagecall" style="width:75%;float:right;" onchange="davsele(this.value);">
<?php
    $totalPage = $dataget['total'] / 20;
    for($i=1;$i<=$totalPage;$i++)
    {
        $selc = ($getPageCount==$i)?'selected':'';
        echo "<option value=".$i." $selc>Page No. ".$i."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you share the "davsele" function, the form "action" and any submit button/input

Comment: function davsele(sval)
  {
   
   //run curl +sval
   //window.location.href = 'admin.php?page=woocommerce_g2a?page='+sval;
  }

Comment: <label for="comment">Select Page:</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="pagecall" id="pagecall" style="width:75%;float:right;" onchange="davsele(this.value);">
        <?php
         $totalPage = $dataget['total'] / 20;
         for($i=1;$i<=$totalPage;$i++)
         {
          $selc = ($getPageCount==$i)?'selected':'';
          echo "<option value=".$i." $selc>Page No. ".$i."</option>";
         }
        ?>
       </select>

Comment: I don't know how the url with 2 "?" is parsed by the server but it is not common. For a GET request the param/value pair are separated by "&". There is a single "?" to separate the page url and the GET request content

Comment: i change it to this still nothing

/woo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=woocommerce_g2a/assets/guiStructure.php&page=8

Comment: also 2 parameters with same name...

Comment: what url do you want to reach ?

Comment: trying to change content inside a plugin.

https://ibb.co/8K5cbbS

Comment: maybe but in example you gave here in comments the url is about admin.php and guiStructure.php. What is the url of the webservice (the page) providing the data ?

Comment: https://products-export-api.g2a.com/v1/

Comment: Fixed formatting

Comment: i think so, the curl parameter is this CURLOPT_URL => "https://products-export-api.g2a.com/v1/products?page=$getPageCount",

Comment: i think so, the curl parameter is this 


  function davsele(sval)
  {

  window.location.href = 'admin.php?page=woocommerce_g2a%page=' + sval;

  }